# Collating data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following statement to try and collect and display data correctly. It is necessary to to a 'LEFT JOIN' with one table to collect more information, but I should say that it's not necessary to do this for the second case (but such is my work-around).

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(building.campus_id, campus.campus_id) AS campus 
    member.*
FROM location
LEFT JOIN cu_member AS member ON
    (member.member_id = location.member_id)
LEFT JOIN cu_building AS building ON
    (location.params LIKE 'building_id=%' = building.id) 
LEFT JOIN cu_campus AS campus ON
    (location.params LIKE 'campus_id=%' = campus.id)
```

I'm my above query, I would want to use the wildcard value.

```
LEFT JOIN cu_building AS building ON
    ('39' = building.id)
```

Below is how my `location` table looks. I'm trying to use the data from the `params` column to get the resulting `campus` from another table (`building`). I only need to do this for fields containing the `building_id` tag, not for those with 'campus_id`, because that is already known.

```
-----------------------------
 member_id  | params  
-----------------------------
 1          | building_id=39
 2          | building_id=24
 3          | campus_id=6
 4          | campus_id=3
 5          | building_id=11
 6          | campus_id=14
 7          | building_id=15
```

This is how my `building` table looks. It lists which building is part of which campus.

```
--------------------------
 building_id  | campus_id 
--------------------------
 39           | 5
 24           | 4
 11           | 2
 15           | 2
```

I have another table named `campus'. My problem is, this table only lists, but I was hoping to use this table in order to display the correct data in the final result.

```
--------------------------
 campus_id   | name 
--------------------------
 6           | ...
 3           | ..
 14          | .
```

The result I want to achieve with the MySQL query is this. Here, the collected results are shown in one table.

```
-----------------------------
 member_id  | campus  
-----------------------------
 1          | 5                      (building_id=39)
 2          | 4                      (building_id=24)
 3          | 6                      (campus_id=6)
 4          | 3                      (campus_id=3)
 5          | 2                      (building_id=11)
 6          | 14                     (campus_id=14)
 7          | 2                      (building_id=15)
```

Comment: Your `params` column in the `location` table is an abomination. Don't put embedded meaning in the content.

Comment: My mistake. My `campus` table just has one column of IDs. The remaining columns are superfluous. My intention was to have a LEFT JOIN to this table for the sole purpose of displaying that ID (where `campus_id=` appears in the `parameters` column of the first table.)

Comment: This whole thing is a mess. The location table structure needs to be revised (or removed entirely), but that may not be possible. The query you are trying makes little sense. Why do you start from the location table in LEFT JOIN on member table? You are not SELECTing anything from location... this JOIN will pull in NULL rows which seem to be useless. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

First things first. **You really need to revise your database structure.** That location table will give you an infinite number of problems, complicating each and every query you ever need to join members with buildings and campuses. As per the data shown, you really should have building_id and campus_id on the member table. Another, softer, solution would be to have a building_id and a campus_id column in the location table.

That said, you do not need neither regex, nor LIKEs to have this query work. Something like this should work adeguately:

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(b.campus_id, c.id) AS campus 
  m.*
FROM      cu_member   m
JOIN      location    l ON l.member_id = m.member_id
LEFT JOIN cu_building b ON l.params = CONCAT('building_id=',b.id)
LEFT JOIN cu_campus   c ON l.params = CONCAT('campus_id=',c.id)
```

I can see that the last join seems a bit redundant, since you really only need the campus id, and not the name or other info. That already resides in the location table, so it would seem unnecessary to JOIN the campus table. The problem is that it is embedded in the params column. Extracting it is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provide, it would be better to expand your params column into a building_id and a campus_id column.

Joining this then becomes very easy.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(building.campus_id, campus.campus_id) AS campus 
    member.*
FROM location
LEFT JOIN cu_member AS member ON     (member.member_id = location.member_id)
LEFT JOIN cu_building AS building ON (location.building_id = building.building_id) 
LEFT JOIN cu_campus AS campus ON     (location.campus_id = campus.campus_id)
```

If there are other reasons here that make creating separate columns difficult, then use the code provided by @Frazz